# C# - How do I find the process id of a separate program?

Tags: c#, .net

I need the process ID for a program that is already running on the computer. How would I go about doing this? (The process isn't started from Process.Start())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [GetProcessesByName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9(v=vs.110).aspx) or just [GetProcesses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9(v=vs.110).aspx) with a bit of LINQ, depending on how you intend to identify the program.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;


void Example()
{
        // Get all processes running on the local computer.
        var localProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();

        //Get all processes with a name that contain "Foo" in the title
        var fooProcess = localProcesses.Where(p => p.MainWindowTitle.Contains("Foo"));

        // Get all instances of Notepad running on the local computer.
        var notepad = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").Single();
}
```

Once you have the Process object, you can get its ID with the [Id](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.id(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

```
var id = process.Id;
```

Comment: I am confused by this answer. I need the process id of a process that is running on the PC. This example does not show anything about converting name to id.

Comment: You get the [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) object first. From there you get the [Id](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.id(v=vs.110).aspx).